# Having trouble with DOM nodes and instanceof

Tags: javascript, dom

OK, I have a little function walking the tree like this:

```
function walkTree(node, func, args) {
    func(node, args);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkTree(node, func, args);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

And another function that would pick up only the text nodes like so:

```
function selectTextNodes(node, nodes) {
    if (node instanceof Text) {
        nodes.push(node);
    }
}
```

And finally, using both:

```
texts = [];
walkTree(body, selectTextNodes, texts);
```

However, it doesn't fill the list at all!

If I were to modify the test as to use `Node.nodeType` it would work:

```
function selectTextNodes(node, nodes) {
    if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        nodes.push(node);
    }
}
```

On the other hand, in the console it works both ways:

```
t = window.document.createTextNode("test");
r = (t.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) && (t instanceof Text);
```

That is, r is true.

Note that, all functions are nested inside another function that receives the `body` variable. In my case, this is the `contentDocument.body` of an `iframe`. There is no x-domain restriction being applied.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are different `Text` interfaces in the different windows. So, if you have a DOM node from your iframe document, it is not an `instanceof window.Text`, but an `instanceof iframe.contentWindow.Text`. Afaik, also the availability of the `Text` interface as a Javascript object is non-standard.

That is why you just should check the `nodeType` of the elements. But notice that (older?) IE does not support the `TEXT_NODE` constant on `Node`, so you will either need to compare with `3` or assign that value as a polyfill to `Node.TEXT_NODE`.

Comment: Superb answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, it's non-standard, but already [living standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text).

Answer (score 1):

## Main document

```
<body>
  <iframe name="ifr" id="ifr" src='test1.html'></iframe>
  <button onclick="clkfn()">test</button>

  <script>

    function wrapper(body, iframeWindow) {
      function walkTree(node, func, args) {
        func(node, args);
        node = node.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            walkTree(node, func, args);
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
      }

      function selectTextNodes(node, nodes) {
          if (node instanceof iframeWindow.Text) {
              nodes.push(node);
          }
      }    

      texts = [];
      walkTree(body, selectTextNodes, texts);

      for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {    
        console.log("text #" + i + texts[i].nodeValue);
      }
    }

    function clkfn() {
      var ifr = frames["ifr"];
      wrapper(ifr.document.body, ifr);
    }

  </script>


</body>
```

## iFrame

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      how are you?
      I am fine. Thank you!
    </body>
</html>
```

## console

When you click on the button, console prints:

> ```
>    text #0  
>         how are you?  
>         I am fine. Thank you!
> ```

Only change made to code is passed the iframe body and window. Then referred the Text object from iFrame window.

Comment: Sorry I should've explained better. This code is actually wrapped up in a function which receives the body object. In reality body is actually the contentDocument.body of an iframe.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: Tried the new code with iFrame now. Referred the Text as iFrameWindow.Text and it works. Can't set the demo now due to iFrame involvement.

Comment: Thanks raghaw, this indeed confirms what Bergi said.